# Efficiently derive parameter from generics vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado, ghdl

I have two generics on my entity:

```
clk_freq, io_delay: integer
```

From this, I want to calculate the number of cycles required for `io_delay` which is in ms. I also want to store this counter value in an unsigned variable so I'm not wasting loads of resources on an integer type. So I've implemented the following to do this:

```
constant COUNT_MAX_I: integer := integer(ceil(real(io_delay) * 0.001 * real(clk_freq)));
constant COUNTER_WIDTH: integer := integer(ceil(log2(real(COUNT_MAX_I))));
constant COUNT_HIGH: integer := unsigned(COUNTER_WIDTH - 1 downto 0) := to_unsigned(COUNT_MAX_I, COUNTER_WIDTH);
```

However, just looking at it that looks hugely inefficient. So my question is this:

Is there a more efficient way to do this and will the synthesis tools get rid of `COUNT_MAX_I` as it's only used in the calculation of other constants?

Comment: @user1155120 which part looks wrong?  OP is declaring an `unsigned` vector constant (numeric_std) of a specific width and assigning a constant value to it.

Comment: **constant** identifier_list **:** subtype_indication [ **:=** expression ] **;** (You were in too much of a hurry to render your opinion to notice.)

Comment: @user1155120 right.  I assumed `integer :=`. is stray as it doesn't fit the rest of the statement.

Comment: Why is the question closed as "opinion-based"?  Please re-open.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that defines a metric for 'efficient' (or inefficient). [There is a quote from `Through the Looking-Glass`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty#Lewis_Carroll's_Through_the_Looking-Glass) that demonstrates the ambiguity leaving only room for opinion. "When I use a word,*" Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, "it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less."* Therein a dispute over the meaning of the word glory.

Comment: You look up @Tricky 's `inefficient` and you get *not achieving maximum productivity; wasting or failing to make the best use of time or resources* which gets you no closer without defining whether it's a productivity issue, a use of time issue, or a use of resource issue. The question goal is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking `constant` declarations themselves do not directly result in any synthesized logic.  As such, there is nothing inefficient about the code as written.

Comment: That's great, thanks! Is there a more direct way to achieve this though? It may not effect the efficiency of the overall solution but it seems inefficient code wise

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inefficient"? Its just some constants calculated at elaboration time.

Comment: @Persistence VHDL tends to be a bit _verbose_ when all you want is to calculate the number of bits for a counter from 0..N-1.  But the amount of time the compiler is likely to spend elaborating and evaluating those constant expressions is negligible (unless you're instantiating millions of them).

Comment: If you want some "cleaner" code, you can use a function to encapsulate the computation of COUNTER_WIDTH and/or COUNT_HIGH. Nonetheless, as @Tricky said, the complexity you use to compute any value that is elaborated as a constant, will be irrelevant for synthesis/runtime. In fact, it is typical to write quite complex parameter computation logic when describing generic hardware.